# Excel files are not being read in application

Tags: php, excel

When uploading an excel file to be inserted its data to database the program doesn't reads 
require_once('excel_reader2.php') function. Here is the portion of the code:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                $this->load->view('form');
                return;         
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/file/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);         
                rename($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/file/".$_FILES["file"]["name"],$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/file/".$name);
            }

            require_once('excel_reader2.php');
            $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/file/".$name);

            $this->load->view('form');
```

I have tested the code several times and each time it fails to proceed further when it reaches the 
require_once('excel_reader2.php') segment of the code. If I comment out that line then error message shows
that Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader is not working as it is declared inside the excel_reader2.php file. And also the form
of last line is loaded if both require and spreadsheet functions are omitted. What could be the exact problem?

Comment: Anything in your error log?

Comment: before the code segment stated in the question "error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); " exists. I didn't mentioned thinking not relevant.

Comment: Post `excel_reader2.php`, I think you have an error in any class present in that file, and post the error !!!

Comment: I have checked that file in other program. It works there but not in the current project.